# ui-sref link send angular values empty

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

`sref` tag in my view and I set some parameters and send to another view

my `ui-sref` tag like

```
a ui-sref="packages.version({id: '{{ctrl.myarray[0].id}}', version: '{{ctrl.versions[0].SemanticVersion}}',SourcePath:'{{ctrl.model.SourcePath}}'})">
```

and in my router it is defined like that

```
.state('packages.version', {
................
        params: {
            id: null,
            version: null,
            SourcePath: null
        },
```

if I send static value to `ui-sref` it is working no problem, but when I want to send it dynamically with my angular value `ui-sref` not send my values,send empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving away the curly braces and quotes in your options:

```
<a ui-sref="packages.version({
    id: ctrl.myarray[0].id,
    version: ctrl.versions[0].SemanticVersion, 
    SourcePath: ctrl.model.SourcePath
})"></a>
```